# birational equivalence of linear sections of algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be an irreducible algebraic variety and suppose that $L$ is a linear space defined by the linear forms $l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_k$. I want to study $L\cap X$. I would like to know whether the following argument is correct and I would appreciate very much a reference:

The linear sections of $X$ are all birational equivalent and the birational map between $X \cap V(l_1)$ and $X \cap V(l')$ will preserve also the degree. So the dimension and the degree of $X\cap L$ will be the same of the dimension and the degree of $X\cap L'$, with $L'$ defined by $l',l_2,\ldots,l_k$.

Comment: In general the linear sections are *not* birational equivalent. As a silly example, take as $X$ a smooth quadric surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and consider a linear section given by a smooth conic and one given by two incident lines.

Comment: The part after "So" is more or less right: the dimension will be constant in a dense open subset of the space of linear forms, and all those varieties will have the same degree. But the statement about birational equivalence is totally false. For instance, the plane sections of a smooth cubic surface over $\mathbf C$ are not all isomorphic (=birational). Do you really want the "birational" part, or just equality of degree and dimension?

Comment: For a less trivial example, take the $d$-ple Veronese embedding $\mathbb{P}^2 \subset \mathbb{P}^N$. The linear sections of the image correspond to the linear system of  curves of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, and two general curves in this system  are *not* birationally equivalent as soon as $d \geq 3$.

Comment: Yes, but both have dimension 1 and degree 2, so I can say that I obtain something of the same degree and dimension. Can I use this in some way? (I am referring to your first comment)

Comment: Ok, so birational is not correct at all, the only thing I need is that the intersection with the new linear space has the same dimension and degree, nothing more...so should I use homological equivalence?

Comment: Yes. The degree of the hyperplane section is precisely $H^{\dim X}$, where $H$ is the hyperplane class. So it is independent by the chosen section. The dimension is always $\dim X -1$ by Krull's theorem.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: but the OP wants to intersect $X$ with a linear subspace of _arbitrary_ codimension. Hence my babble about dense open sets, etc.

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith: ah, ok thanks. In this case, one should be more careful as you correctly remark. (A general line through a fixed point do not intersect a twisted cubic, but there are infinitely many secant lines and one bisecant line).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. So if $X\cap L$ is a finite set of points, I cannot use that anymore, I mean, if the dimension and the degree coincide in an open subset, it can happen that $X\cap L$ consist of $d$  points but $X\cap L'$ is empty (as in the example of @Francesco)